# Mail server rdns setup not right

Tags: email, dns

I am running a Zimbra virtual machine on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

I am getting a few emails returned to me with this message:

```
<46e6820d4d3532509d8603ba1546406a@reply.craigslist.org>: host
    mxia.craigslist.org[208.82.237.85] refused to talk to me: 554
    [1F14D9E7-73BD-489F-AC79-4E640DB27254@mxi6a]
    coldmail.co.xx.xx.xx.in-addr.arpa [xx.xx.xx.xx] Please setup matching DNS
    and rDNS records: http://www.craigslist.org/about/help/rdns_failure
```

I run this on a virtual machine running on a dedicated server that I rent. My host assures me that the rdns record is setup correctly to my domain.

When I check on http://mxtoolbox.com/ they are returning this to me:

[image]

Is this something I need to correct on my virtual machine setup or is it something I need to get my host to correct?

Comment: Which part of "under the hood" at https://www.craigslist.org/about/help/rdns_failure don't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to contact support at your host to have this resolved.

Some hosts - godaddy in particular, even with their so called dedicated servers (don't get me started) - funnel all mail out through their own mail server so rDNS resolves to their server not yours.  The only way I was ever able to resolve this was to move to a new hosting company.